# Toggle Element Should Block Content Underneath

Tags: html, jquery, css, toggle

How do I make a toggle element block all the content underneath? I tried width, height 100% but it cuts off my content within the toggle element

Comment: What do you mean by "*block all the content underneath*"? "*Underneath*" as in lower down the screen, or "behind" the "*toggle element*"? You say you "*tried width, height...*" but what code (CSS, and HTML) did you use? If you don't share your code it's very hard to offer any help, and without clarity it's very hard - currently - to understand what you're asking us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by doing the following

```
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
```

overflow-y: auto; ensures that any content that doesn't fit into the viewport can still get scrolled to